# Iterate from specific index

Tags: java

This loop iterates from list's beginning to its last index but I want to iterate from any specific index.

```
 for (Object ob : objlist) 
    {
    //code
    }
```

I don't want to iterate using list.size().
I want to iterate from any specific list index and onwards...

Comment: simple for loop ? `for(count=index;count<endIndex;count++)` perhaps ?

Comment: You kind of need to use `objList.size()`... otherwise how would you know when to stop iterating? You do realize that the iterator you have in your question probably uses `objList.size()`, right?

Comment: @Jashaszun : I agree and I can do it but the problem is that i want want to use list[i] for calling any method & my LOC is near about 500 lines so it will be difficult to edit every where that is why I am looking for any alternative.

Comment: `list[i]` like array of lists?

Comment: @ShashiRanjan Not sure what you mean. In Java you can't use `list[i]`, for one, since it's not an array.

Comment: @ShashiRanjan do you mean that `list.get(i)` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They you probably want a vanilla `for` loop:

```
for (int i = startIndex; i < objList.size(); i++)
{
    Object ob = objList.get(i);
    // code
}
```

Comment: I forgot to mention in the post that i don't want to iterate using list.size().

Comment: @ShashiRanjan Can you edit your post to include what you mean in detail please ?

Comment: @ShashiRanjan when did your aversion to `list.size()` start?

Comment: actually I can't say that but according to requirement I have to implement thi

Comment: @ShashiRanjan I think what you are trying to accomplish is unclear. Please edit your question to include relevant details, to iterate a list of objects why would you need to change everywhere in 500 lines of code ?

Comment: Dear I am parsing XML and that is why the object is used every where at the time of writing XML

Answer (score 4):

You can have a standard `for` loop:

```
for (int i = start; i < objList.size(); i++)
```

or you can use an enhanced `for` loop on a *sublist*, using [`List`'s `subList` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList-int-int-):

```
for (Object ob : objList.subList(start, objList.size()))
```

Answer (score 2):

For whatever type T is in your list,

```
ListIterator<T> iterator = objList.listIterator(index);
while( iterator.hasNext() ) {
  T item = iterator.next();
  // do stuff
}
```